# Getting Rock, Paper, Scissors?

Tags: javascript

'm working on a simple rock paper scissors script for the Odin Project as part of the course; every answer I get is towards when I run it in the console is ("Draw") no matter what I put in; what am I doing wrong?

Here is the link to the assignment - I know if I took out the various functions I could most likely make it work, but the brief is to use these specific functions hence the issue.

I think the issue might lie in the playerSelection function, but I can't be sure? Would appreciate a little guidance.

Odin Project link: https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-rock-paper-scissors

```js
let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

function computerPlay() {
  let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  return randomChoice = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
}

function playerSelection() {
  let playerChoice = prompt("Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors");
}

function playRound(computerPlay, playerSelection) {
  if (computerPlay === "Rock" && playerSelection === "Scissors") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (computerPlay === "Paper" && playerSelection === "Rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (computerPlay === "Scissors" && playerSelection === "Paper") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerPlay === "Scissors") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerPlay === "Rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerPlay === "Paper") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else {
    return "Draw";
  }
}

playerSelection()
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: Trace through your code and make sure the local variables in `playRound` have the values you think they do. I suspect that, with a bit of debugging, you'll find that one of those variables has an unusual type.

Comment: `"Enter Rock, or Paper, or Scissors"`, but what if I enter `'rock'`? `'rock' === 'Rock'` is `false` after all.

Comment: I was gonna work on that next - but having issues just running the code even with the "Rock" input - do you think it could be because of the final else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have some bugs:

1. You don't call playerSelection function in console.log()
2. You don't return value from playerSelection() function
3. You have two arguments in playRound function (1: computerPlay, 2: playerSelection) but you call playRound with messed up order of arguments.
4. You have extra call for playerSelection function()

```js
//let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    function computerPlay() {
        let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
        return randomChoice = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
    }

    function playerSelection() {
        // 2) add return
        return prompt("Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors");
    }

    // 3) change order for arguments
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay) {
        console.log(`Computer choose ${computerPlay}`);
        if (computerPlay === "Rock" && playerSelection === "Scissors") {
            return "Computer wins";
        } else if (computerPlay === "Paper" && playerSelection === "Rock") {
            return "Player wins";
        } else if (computerPlay === "Scissors" && playerSelection === "Paper") {
            return "Computer wins";
        } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerPlay === "Scissors") {
            return "Computer wins";
        } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerPlay === "Rock") {
            return "Player wins";
        } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerPlay === "Paper") {
            return "Player wins";
        } else {
            return "Draw";
        }
    }

    // 4) remove playerSelection call
    // playerSelection()
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    // 1) add call to playerSelection() function
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection(), computerSelection));
```

P.s. you have to use object to find winner:

```js
function computerPlay() {
        let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
        return randomChoice = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
    }

    function playerSelection() {
        return prompt("Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors");
    }

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay) {
        console.log(`player: ${playerSelection} VS  + computer: ${computerPlay}`);
        if (playerSelection === computerPlay) return 'Draw'
        const winPairs = {
            Paper: 'Rock',
            Scissors: 'Paper',
            Rock: 'Scissors'
        }
        return winPairs[playerSelection] === computerPlay ? 'Player wins' : 'Computer wins'
    }
    
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection(), computerPlay()));
```

Comment: Your object solution is very slim - cool!

Answer (score 1):

Like the others wrote, your prompt never "lands" in the `if` chain, so that every time the last `else` statement is called.

The easiest way would be, to omit the other two functions and insert their two neccesary lines in the function `playRound()`.

**Working example:**

```js
const choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

function playRound() {
  const computerSelection = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
  const playerSelection = prompt("Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors");
  
  if (computerSelection === "Rock" && playerSelection === "Scissors") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (computerSelection === "Paper" && playerSelection === "Rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (computerSelection === "Scissors" && playerSelection === "Paper") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    return "Computer wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else {
    return "Draw";
  }
}

console.log(playRound());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `playerSelection` function is not returning the selection but just declaring a variable with the output of the `prompt` function as its output. You should return the variable like this:

```
function playerSelection() {
   let playerChoice = prompt("Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors"); 
   return playerChoice
}
```

This is why it is returning "Draw"

Comment: I tried but no luck - it seems whatever I enter, even a random letter, it still returns Draw

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

First, you're calling the `playerSelection` function at the bottom without getting the value and assigning it to a variable to pass to the `playRound` function. Change this to:

```
    const playerChoice = playerSelection() 
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(playRound(playerChoice, computerSelection));
```

Secondly, your `playerSelection` function is never returning the selected choice, change this to:

```
  function playerSelection() {
    let playerChoice = prompt('Enter Rock or Paper or Scissors');
    return playerChoice;
  }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ojw975mL6lfsrSOn?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

Comment: It's not full list of problems, check order of arguments in playRound function and in call of playRound functions